# Javascript addEventListener does it matter what the name of the function is in the second parameter?

Tags: javascript

Does it matter what the name of the function is in the second parameter of the addEventListern(Parm1, Parm2, Parm3)

I think that the error might have been because not all of the calls were renamed to that specific function name. There are a couple of times when that function is called and I think that would be what probably is causing the errors.

My code works with the below code. You can drag the circle around the canvas.

```
 theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
```

But if I change the code to the following.

```
 theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", er, false);
```

And also rename the mouseDownListener method to er I can drag the circle around but when I release the mouse the circle keeps following the mouse pointer around. This seems like an odd behavior and I am not certain as to why this would be.

**Question: Does the second parameter function name have to be mouseDownListener exactly or can this be an ad hoc name?**

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   h4 {font-family: sans-serif;}
   p {font-family: sans-serif;}
   a {font-family: sans-serif; color:#d15423; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
<title>HTML5 Canvas Example - Simple Dragging Objects</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", canvasApp, false);

var Debugger = function() { };

Debugger.log = function(message) {
    try {
        console.log(message);
    }
    catch (exception) {
        return;
    }
}

function canvasApp() {
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    var context   = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    init();

    var numShapes;
    var shapes;
    var dragIndex;
    var dragging;
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    var dragHoldX;
    var dragHoldY;

    function init() {
        numShapes = 1;
        shapes    = [];
        makeShapes();
        drawScreen();
        theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
    }

    function makeShapes() {
        var i;
        var tempX;
        var tempY;
        var tempRad;
        var tempR;
        var tempG;
        var tempB;
        var tempColor;

            for (i=0; i < numShapes; i++) {
                tempRad = 10 + Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
                tempX = Math.random()*(theCanvas.width  - tempRad);
                tempY = Math.random()*(theCanvas.height - tempRad);
                tempR = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                tempG = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                tempB = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                tempColor = "rgb(" + tempR + "," + tempG + "," + tempB +")";
                tempShape = {x:tempX, y:tempY, rad:tempRad, color:tempColor};
                shapes.push(tempShape);
            }
    }

     //main function for when the mouse button is clicked -- Once everything is loaded everything depends on this function     
    function mouseDownListener(evt) {
        var i;
        var highestIndex = -1;

        var bRect = theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left)*(theCanvas.width/bRect.width);
        mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top)*(theCanvas.height/bRect.height);

        //find which shape was clicked
        for (i=0; i < numShapes; i++) {
            if  (hitTest(shapes[i], mouseX, mouseY)) {
                dragging = true;
                    if (i > highestIndex) {
                        dragHoldX = mouseX - shapes[i].x;
                        dragHoldY = mouseY - shapes[i].y;
                        highestIndex = i;
                        dragIndex = i;
                    }
            }
        }

        if (dragging) {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
        }

        theCanvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);

        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } //standard
        else if (evt.returnValue) {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        } //older IE
    return false;
    }


   function mouseUpListener(evt) {
        theCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);
        window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpListener, false);

        if (dragging) {
            dragging = false;
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveListener, false);
        }
     }

    function mouseMoveListener(evt) {
        var posX;
        var posY;
        var shapeRad = shapes[dragIndex].rad;
        var minX = shapeRad;
        var maxX = theCanvas.width - shapeRad;
        var minY = shapeRad;
        var maxY = theCanvas.height - shapeRad;

        var bRect = theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left)*(theCanvas.width/bRect.width);
        mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top)*(theCanvas.height/bRect.height);

        posX = mouseX - dragHoldX;
        posX = (posX < minX) ? minX : ((posX > maxX) ? maxX : posX);
        posY = mouseY - dragHoldY;
        posY = (posY < minY) ? minY : ((posY > maxY) ? maxY : posY);

        shapes[dragIndex].x = posX;
        shapes[dragIndex].y = posY;

        drawScreen();
    }

    function hitTest(shape,mx,my) {
        var dx;
        var dy;
        dx = mx - shape.x;
        dy = my - shape.y;
        return (dx*dx + dy*dy < shape.rad*shape.rad);
    }

    function drawShapes() {
        var i;

        for (i=0; i < numShapes; i++) {
            context.fillStyle = shapes[i].color;
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(shapes[i].x, shapes[i].y, shapes[i].rad, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
        }
    }

    function erraseCanvas() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
    }

    function clearTheScreenWithRectangle() {
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillRect(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
    }

    function drawScreen() {
        //erraseCanvas();
        clearTheScreenWithRectangle();
        drawShapes();                 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="top: 50px; text-align:center">
    <canvas id="canvasOne" width="1000" height="500">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to rename the function in `theCanvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownListener, false);` as well. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). You should see an appropriate error in the console.

Comment: And FWIW, the callee only gets *value*. It doesn't know where the value comes from, how it was computed.

Comment: The parameter can be any name that is legally valid in Javascript. I would name it something similar to what you are actually doing such as load. (Answer posted below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter has to be a reference to the function you want called when the event is triggered.

When passing a function, you may call it *any*, **valid** javascript identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The second function can be called anything.  The behaviour you describe by renaming the function to `er` could be caused if you forget to rename *every* occurrence of the function name (especially where it is disabled etc)

Answer (score 1):

No, ceiling cat does not force you to set your function names to anything. You have freedom to name it whatever you like.

The second parameter is just a reference to the function you defined earlier, you can put any function (even anonymous) there.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in in this statement can be any valid javascript name.

```
   window.addEventListener("load", canvasApp, false);
```

Can be any valid name in Javascript that you want it to me.

```
   window.addEventListener("load", ILoveBaseballANDApplePie, false);
   window.addEventListener("load", Pizza, false);
   window.addEventListener("load", AnyOtherName, false);


   function Pizza() {
       //do some code here
   }

   function ILoveBaseballANDApplePie() {
       //do some code here
   }
```

For programming purposes I would add the "load" name to the function name some how just so that 2 years later you will remember that that the function has to do with the load parameter. I would purchase a simple book on Javascript and use Notepad++ to go through some simple examples because even after using Javascript for the past 6 months I still find it somewhat of a beast to contend with on some things. With HTML5 you will be using these events probably a lot so I would learn as much as I possibly could about Javascript events.

Comment: I liked your answer but the one that I accepted was answered before yours. I thought all of the answers were good.